# How to take the price of an amazon page with python using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Hi i just started studying selenium and i wanted to create a program that would tell me the price of an amazon page. However I just can't go on. Where am I doing wrong?

This is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By




driver=webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00CDD2GU4'
driver.get(url)

try:
   price_parent = item.find('span','a-price')
   price = price_parent.find('span','a-offscreen').text.replace('$','')
except Exception as e:
   price_parent = '0'
   price = '0'



print(price)
```

I also used this code that I found online

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00CDD2GU4'
driver.get(url)
price = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span.a-price.a-text-price.a-size-medium span.a-offscreen").get_attribute("innerText")
print(price)
```

But I get this:

```
PS C:\Users\mrcdi> & C:/Users/mrcdi/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe "c:/Users/mrcdi/Desktop/Amazon Seller/Programma/prova.py"

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:64657/devtools/browser/fe6d839b-0f11-4f55-a192-9052f838a98d
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\mrcdi\Desktop\Amazon Seller\Programma\prova.py", line 11, in <module>
    price = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span.a-price.a-text-price.a-size-medium span.a-offscreen").get_attribute("innerText")
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mrcdi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 740, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\mrcdi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 346, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\mrcdi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"span.a-price.a-text-price.a-size-medium span.a-offscreen"}
  (Session info: chrome=115.0.5790.102); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00ABA813+48355]
        (No symbol) [0x00A4C4B1]
        (No symbol) [0x00955358]
        (No symbol) [0x009809A5]
        (No symbol) [0x00980B3B]
        (No symbol) [0x009AE232]
        (No symbol) [0x0099A784]
        (No symbol) [0x009AC922]
        (No symbol) [0x0099A536]
        (No symbol) [0x009782DC]
        (No symbol) [0x009793DD]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00D1AABD+2539405]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00D5A78F+2800735]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00D5456C+2775612]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00B451E0+616112]
        (No symbol) [0x00A55F8C]
        (No symbol) [0x00A52328]
        (No symbol) [0x00A5240B]
        (No symbol) [0x00A44FF7]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x762900C9+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77DA7B1E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77DA7AEE+238]
```

I am new to selenium so please can you help me?

This is a screen
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element with the price text is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00CDD2GU4")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#ape_Detail_desktop-detail-ilm_desktop_iframe")))
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[data-testid='price']"))).text)
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00CDD2GU4")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='ape_Detail_desktop-detail-ilm_desktop_iframe']")))
    print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@data-testid='price']"))).text)
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

---

### Update

Given the HTML:

[image: html]

you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.a-offscreen"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='a-offscreen']"))).text)
  ```

Comment: So my code looks now like this
"""
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00CDD2GU4")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#ape_Detail_desktop-detail-ilm_desktop_iframe")))
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[data-testid='price']"))).text)

"""

But I dont get the prices. My output is always: 
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50337/devtools/browser/2b86f271-48e0-4cd0-94de-95f8790a3ad7
$
47
73

Comment: @MarcoDiGiacomo Watch that`$ 47 73` , this is the price, right? You need micro adjustments using python liabries.

Comment: It is not, the price should be 89.90

Comment: where is that price on the screen? I don't find any price as **89.90** on that page.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot to my post. now I restarted the program and it gives me a different number:
159
99

Maybe you dont find the same price because of your location. I am located in Germany

Comment: @MarcoDiGiacomo The segment containing the price isn't vivible from APAC region. Checkout the answer update and let me know the status.

Comment: Do you want to move the discussion to chat?
Because the errors are too long to write them as a comment @undetected Selenium

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254615/discussion-between-marco-di-giacomo-and-undetected-selenium).

Comment: Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.

Comment: Check this discussion [_**NoSuchElementException**_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47995294/7429447)